# how to call a package/project of libgdx into android project

Tags: android, libgdx

Is it possible to call a libgdx project on some event generation of android like
`onTouch`/`onClick`

```
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
   case R.id.imgb1:
     libgdxproj1;
     break;
   case R.id.imgb2:
     libgdxproj2;
     break;
   }
}
```

I'm new to libgdx and andoid.

Answer (score 3):

Libgdx core is running on an Activity, for example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = false;
        cfg.useAccelerometer = false;
        cfg.useCompass = false;
        cfg.useWakelock = true;

        initialize(new GameName(), cfg);
    }
}
```

So if you want to call it from another Activity, just:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);      
finish();
```

Comment: what if ,when to call it on click or on fling of button/image